# How can I fix trouble with event ended with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I created a liitle pet-project like player for sounds with jQuery and have some problems with event "ended" of tag "audio". My code is working but not last function with "ended". I do not understand what is wrong. I hope a people from stackoverflow help me to confirm this problem.

Its my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-play', function () {
  $(this).next('.play-audio').trigger('play');
  $(this).nextAll('.button-pause').toggle();
  $(this).toggle();
});
$(document).on('click', '.button-pause', function () {
  $(this).prev('.play-audio').trigger('pause');
  $(this).prevAll('.button-play').toggle();
  $(this).toggle();
  });
$(document).on('ended', '.play-audio', function () {
  $('.button-play').toggle();
  $('.button-pause').toggle();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because Media events - such as `ended` in this case - do not bubble up the DOM, so you cannot use them in delegated event handlers. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event)

For the code to work you will need to attach the `ended` event directly to the `audio` element for the handler to work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code, now its working but only one time. This function only works once.

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-play', function () {
    $(this).next('.play-audio').on('ended', function () {
      $(this).prev('.button-play').toggle();
      $(this).next('.button-pause').toggle();
    });
  });
```